# shell script to read metadata file line by line and take those text as search pattern to find files placed in another directory

Tags: bash, design-patterns, find

I have a directory(say: myDir) with many files dynamically populated inside it

I have a another meta data file with some texts inside it. Eg:
cust_order
cust_mgmt
...
...

I need to write a script to read that meta data file line by line and use that text as search pattern to find files with same name which were placed in the directory(myDir). Kindly help to write shell script for this scenario.

Thanks,
vivek

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I have a metadata file(say mtfile.log) which contains texts
IP_CUS
AR_MSMT_SPOT

And I have directory called mydir which has following files
AK2056-BKS-CLF-AR_MSMT_SPOT.ctl
AK2056-BKS-CLF-AR_MSMT_SPOT.dat
AK2056-BKS-CLF-AR_PD_RLTSHP.ctl
AK2056-BKS-CLF-AR_PD_RLTSHP.dat
AK2056-BKS-CLF-IP_CUS.ctl
AK2056-BKS-CLF-IP_CUS.dat

I want my script to read mtfile.log file line by line and use text as pattern to compare it with files present in "mydir" and only need .dat files. my desired output from find command should be 

AK2056-BKS-CLF-AR_MSMT_SPOT.dat
AK2056-BKS-CLF-IP_CUS.dat

Comment: I tried to write the script using regex in find like below. But it works improperly and not able to get desired ouput
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line

do

 find /home/***/mydev -type f -regex "*/-$line.dat" -exec chmod 777 {} \;

done < mtfile.log

I did -exec chmod 777 just to check if first part of find properly working

Comment: See my comment: *no comment*